# Executar evento somente se um outro evento já tiver sido executado

Tags: javascript, eventos

Possuo dois ouvintes para o evento *scroll* e preciso que o segundo seja executado somente se o primeiro já foi executado anteriormente, apenas uma vez, até que o primeiro evento seja executado novamente. Por exemplo, possuo os evento X e Y; X só poderá executar se o evento Y já foi executado anteriormente e só poderá ser executado de novo quando Y também for executado novamente, como uma espécie de *restart* do evento X.

Como fazer algo assim em JavaScript?

Comment: Para maior assertividade na resposta poderia mencionar quais seriam os nomes desses eventos X e Y?

Comment: Bem, a minha questão é um evento de scroll em uma página web, quando o scroll atinge tal valor, ele fará uma animação em um logotipo, e quando o valor do scroll voltar ao anterior fara outra animação, porém a segunda animação só pode ocorrer caso a primeira ja tiver sido executada antes, e logo após essa segunda caso o valor do scroll mude novamente poderá fazer as animações A ou B somente se a anterior for a oposta!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que você pode fazer é atribuir o ouvinte do segundo evento apenas quando o primeiro evento ocorrer; e, quando executado, remover o ouvinte, para que seja adicionado novamente na execução do primeiro evento. A lógica seria semelhante a essa:

```
function eventoX(event) {
  // ...
  document.removeEventListener('X', eventoX);
}

document.addEventListener('Y', event => {
  // ...
  document.addEventListener('X', eventoX);
});
```

Por exemplo, considerando que ambos os eventos são cliques em botões, vamos fazer com que o evento de clique no botão B só ocorra se o botão A já tiver sido pressionado:

```js
const A = document.getElementById('a');
const B = document.getElementById('b');

function eventoEmB(event) {
  console.log('Você pressionou o botão B');
  B.removeEventListener('click', eventoEmB);
}

A.addEventListener('click', event => {
  console.log('Você pressionou o botão A');
  B.addEventListener('click', eventoEmB);
});
```

```html
<button id="a">Botão A</button>
<button id="b">Botão B</button>
```

Perceba que o evento em B só será disparado se o evento em A tiver sido disparado anteriormente, apenas uma vez.

Comment: Como faço para a partir da primeira vez que o evento B for executado o A só poderá ser executado também se caso o B for executado, no caso a exceção seria apenas o Primeiro A de inicio, o segundo A já necessitaria do B antes dele!

Comment: @Arthur74 isso não fez sentido nenhum para mim. Poderia explicar mais detalhadamente?

Comment: ex: posso pressionar o botao A varias vezes, e todas ele é disparado, o B depende de um disparo anterior do A!
Precisaria que o A só pudesse ser executado a partir da segunda vez, se e somente se o B tiver sido disparado!

Comment: @Arthur74 e não é exatamente isso que a minha resposta faz?

Comment: o inicio sim, porém a partir do segundo disparo do Botão A ele teria que ter as condições igual ao botão B, e só poder ser disparado caso antes tenha sido disparado o B e não ele mesmo.